# Finding an analytic branch in a specific domain of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

I've got some issue on solving the following problem:
Considering the domain $ A = {z \in \Bbb C} $ such that $Re(z)<0$ and $ {\sqrt z} $ is defined as the principal branch, How to find other analytic branch function in relation to this domian?
Offcourse i can't define $g(z) = \pm e^{0.5Log(z)} $ because the slit $(\infty,0] \in A$